# Changing where table starts using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and coding in general, and I'm working on my first website.  I am using a table for the body of the site so that it looks a bit nicer.  My plan was for the table and main body of the site to start right below the header and continue downwards.  I have run into a problem where the table is not taking up the space underneath the header.  Instead, it seems to start way above the beginning of the page.  I changed the body height so that it extends far down to give the table enough space to expand down, but it doesn't.  It only uses a tiny portion of the page, and I do not know how to fix this.  My HTML code is here (I just used the magic and breaks as a temporary filler text for the table cells):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>OTDA - Myths</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="tv.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mythstyle.css" />
</head>
<div id="header">
<header>    
<img class="banner" src="OTDABanner.jpg">

<div class="navigation">
<a href="otda.htm" class="button">Home</a>
<a href="otda.htm" class="button">Donation Station</a>
<a href="otda.htm" class="button">Gift of Life</a>
<a href="otda.htm" class="button">Myths</a>
<a href="otda.htm" class="button">Awareness</a>
</div>
<h1> Myths Regarding <abbr title="Organ and Tissue Donation Awareness">OTDA</h1>
<hr>
</header>
</div>
<body>
<table cellspacing="0">
<colgroup>
    <col style="width:10%">
    <col style="width:80%">
    <col style="width:10%">
  <tr>
    <th></th><!--Don't use these-->
    <th></th><!--Don't use these-->
    <th></th><!--Don't use these-->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th><!--Don't use these-->
    <td>
    </br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br />
    </td>
    <th></th><!--Don't use these-->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th><!--Don't use these-->
    <td>
    </br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br />
    </td>
    <th></th><!--Don't use these-->
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th></th><!--Don't use these-->
    <td>
    </br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br />
    </td>
    <th></th><!--Don't use these-->
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th></th><!--Don't use these-->
    <td>
    </br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br />
    </td>
    <th></th><!--Don't use these-->
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th></th><!--Don't use these-->
    <td
    </br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br /></br />magic<br />
    </td>
    <th></th><!--Don't use these-->
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
</body>
</html>
<!--<div class="container">
<img src="image.png" class="image">
<div class="middle">
<a href="http://www.t.org" height: 250; width: 250; target="_blank" class="button">Website</a>
</div>
</div>-->
```

Here is my CSS:

> /* Body Styles */
>
> body { Background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190); Text-align: justify;
>   Font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif; margin: 0
>   !important; padding: 0 !important; height: 10000px; }
>
> .picture { /* In order to apply this, use  */
>   border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 50%;   /* Images have a circle
>   border */ } .banner {  display: block;  margin: 0 auto; }
>
> a.button {  color: black;  border: 2px ridge black; font-family:
>   "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif; background-color: #ff9191; 
>   padding: 16px 32px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;
>   font-size: 16px; margin: 4px 2px;
>   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;  transition-duration: 0.4s; cursor: pointer; }
>
> a.button:hover {
>       background-color: yellow;
>       color: black; } a { color: black; Text-decoration: none; } a:hover { color: blue; Text-decoration: none; } .navigation { text-align:
>   center; } table.tr { background-color: white; } header {
>   background-color: white; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;
>   } h1 { text-align: center; } .container { position: relative; width:
>   50%; }
>
> .image { opacity: 1; display: block; height: auto; transition: .5s
>   ease; backface-visibility: hidden; border: 2px ridge silver; }
>
> .middle { transition: .5s ease; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top:
>   50%; left: 17%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
>   -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) }
>
> .container:hover .image { opacity: 0.3; }
>
> .container:hover .middle { opacity: 1; }
>
> .text { background-color: #4CAF50; color: white; font-size: 16px;
>   padding: 16px 32px; }
>
> ## header { position: fixed; width: 100%; z-index: 1; }
>
> table { background-color: white; width: 100%; position: absolute;
>   bottom: 0;
>
> height: 100%; } th { Background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190); border: 1px
>   solid rgb(190, 190, 190); height: 1px; } td { border: 1px solid rgb(0,
>   0, 0); height: 1px; } hr { background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190);
>   color: rgb(190, 190, 190); margin: 0px; margin-left: auto;
>   margin-right: auto; height: 10px; border: 0 none; }
>   I apologize if this is hard to read, I'm a very sloppy coder and this was made with haste.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/eGenius18/pen/vmMOVo something like this? btw you should clean up your code. don't put header above body tag, table position must be relative, `</br />` is not valid...

Answer (score 0):

you have header outside your body tag:-

```
    <html>

<head>
    <title>OTDA - Myths</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="tv.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mythstyle.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <header>
            <img class="banner" src="OTDABanner.jpg">
            <div class="navigation">
                <a href="otda.htm" class="button">Home</a>
                <a href="otda.htm" class="button">Donation Station</a>
                <a href="otda.htm" class="button">Gift of Life</a>
                <a href="otda.htm" class="button">Myths</a>
                <a href="otda.htm" class="button">Awareness</a>
            </div>
            <h1> Myths Regarding <abbr title="Organ and Tissue Donation Awareness">OTDA</h1>
            <hr>
        </header>
    </div>
    <table cellspacing="0">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width:10%">
            <col style="width:80%">
            <col style="width:10%">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <!--Don't use these-->
                <th></th>
                <!--Don't use these-->
                <th></th>
                <!--Don't use these-->
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <!--Don't use these-->
                <td>
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                </td>
                <th></th>
                <!--Don't use these-->
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <!--Don't use these-->
                <td>
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                </td>
                <th></th>
                <!--Don't use these-->
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <!--Don't use these-->
                <td>
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                </td>
                <th></th>
                <!--Don't use these-->
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <!--Don't use these-->
                <td>
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                    </br />magic
                    <br />
                </td>
                <th></th>
                <!--Don't use these-->
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <!--Don't use these-->
                <td </br />magic
                <br />
                </br />magic
                <br />
                </br />magic
                <br />
                </br />magic
                <br />
                </br />magic
                <br />
                </br />magic
                <br />
                </br />magic
                <br />
                </br />magic
                <br />
                </td>
                <th></th>
                <!--Don't use these-->
            </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
</body>

</html>
```

someone beat me just to it!